# Is this a studied recurrence?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, recurrence-relations

In a problem I'm working on, I've come across the following recurrence relation; for $w_i$ defined for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, and $c_0 =1$, we define:

$$c_k = -\frac{1}{k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^k c_{k-i}w_i\right)$$

For context, this was derived from the trace of a matrix, using Newton's formulae and Vieta's formulae. The $w_i$ are the power sums, and the $c_i$ are coefficients of the polynomial whose roots we compute using Vieta's formulae. For small examples, it is easy to compute the $w_i$, hence the $c_i$, but I am searching for an analytic relationship between them.

I was wondering if recurrences of this form are well-studied. I've evaluated small terms seeking a pattern in the $w_i$ (I am most concerned with when $c_i$ vanishes, hence when the rightmost factor below vanishes):

$$\begin{cases} c_0 = 1 \\ c_1 = (-1)(w_1) \\ c_2 = (-1)(-1/2)(w_1^2 - w_2) \\ c_3 = (-1)(-1/2)(-1/3)(w_1^3 - 3w_1w_2 + 2w_3) \\ c_4 = (-1)(-1/2)(-1/3)(-1/4)(w_1^4 - 6w_1^2w_2 + 6w_1w_2 + 2w_1w_3 - 3w_2^2 - 6w_4) \end{cases}$$

But nothing is apparent to me.

EDIT:

A comment has requested more information. This question was inspired by a problem in graph theory, but is ultimately involved in understanding the characteristic polynomial of $M \in \mathcal{M}_n(\{0,1\})$, the set of $n$-square matrices with $0,1$ entries.

If we write the characteristic polynomial $\Lambda_M(x) = \det(xI - M)$ as:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n c_ix^{n-i}$$
and write $M$'s eigenvalues as $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$, we can define the power sum of the eigenvalues:

$$w_j = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^j$$

Then using the representation of a power sum in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials (Newton's identity), and that the elementary symmetric polynomials of the eigenvalues can be written in terms of coefficients of $\Lambda_M$ (Vieta's formula) we obtain the above recurrence.

It seems to me that since the actual values of the $w_i$ are a "mystery" for the problems I'm concerned with, a purely combinatorial analysis of the recurrence for $w_i$ unknown might give some insight. In particular, I'm aiming for sufficient conditions for $c_i$ to vanish for small-enough $i$.

Thus understanding this recurrence is at least as hard as understanding the eigenvalues of a directed graph--- but I was curious as to if it was well-studied.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "power sums" for $w_i$? Could you share more details about the problem you're solving?

Answer (score 1):

Usually generating functions are the best way to deal with this kind of recurrences.

Write $C(T) = \sum_{k \geq 0} c_kT^k$ and $W(T) = \sum_{k \geq 1} w_kT^{k - 1}$. The recurrence relations can then be packed into a differential equation of formal power series: $C' = -WC$.

This obviously has solution $C = \exp(-\int W)$ where $\int W$ is the formal integral of $W$, namely $\int W = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{w_k}k T^k$.

Thus we have $\sum_{k \geq 0} c_k T^k = \exp(-\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{w_k}k T^k)$. This kind of constructions appear e.g. in the definition of zeta functions of algebraic varieties over finite fields: see e.g. [local zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_zeta_function).

As you are not presenting an explicit question, I hope this information is enough to point you to eventually useful references.

Comment: I've actually seen that representation in a text elsewhere, but I hadn't made the connection with zeta functions. I'll look into that, thanks!